Empty collection when using Many to Many in Spring Boot
package musicstore.musicselling.Entity;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "artist")
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long artistId;
    private String artistName;
    private String artistBio;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "artist_song", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id", referencedColumnName = "artistId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", referencedColumnName = "songId") })
    private Set<Song> songs = new HashSet<>();

    public Artist() {

    }

    public Artist(String artistName, String artistBio) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.artistBio = artistBio;
    }

    public Long getArtistId() {
        return artistId;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }

    public String getArtistBio() {
        return artistBio;
    }

    public void setArtistBio(String artistBio) {
        this.artistBio = artistBio;
    }

    public Set<Song> getSongs() {
        return songs;
    }

    public void setSongs(Set<Song> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;

    }

    public void addSong(Song song) {
        this.songs.add(song);
        song.getArtists().add(this);
    }

}

package musicstore.musicselling.Entity;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "song")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long songId;
    private String songName;
    private long songStream;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "songs", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Artist> artists = new HashSet<>();

    public Song() {

    }

    public Song(String songName, long songStream) {
        this.songName = songName;
        this.songStream = songStream;
        this.artists = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Long getSongId() {
        return songId;
    }

    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }

    public long getSongStream() {
        return songStream;
    }

    public void setSongStream(long songStream) {
        this.songStream = songStream;
    }

    public Set<Artist> getArtists() {
        return artists;
    }

    public void setArtists(Set<Artist> artists) {
        this.artists = artists;
    }

    public void addArtist(Artist artist) {
        this.artists.add(artist);
        artist.getSongs().add(this);
    }

}

package musicstore.musicselling;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import musicstore.musicselling.Entity.Artist;
import musicstore.musicselling.Entity.Song;
import musicstore.musicselling.Repository.ArtistRepository;
import musicstore.musicselling.Repository.SongRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MusicsellingApplication {
    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ArtistRepository artistRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MusicsellingApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            // create artists
            Artist artist1 = new Artist("Sơn Tùng M-TP", "Vietnamese singer-songwriter and actor.");
            Artist artist2 = new Artist("tlinh", "tlinh is a Vietnamese independent singer and rapper.");
            Artist artist3 = new Artist("RPT MCK", "RPT MCK is a Vietnamese singer and rapper based in Ha Noi.");

            // save artists
            artistRepository.save(artist1);
            artistRepository.save(artist2);
            artistRepository.save(artist3);

            // Create songs and add artists
            Song song1 = new Song("nếu lúc đó", 3794587);
            song1.addArtist(artist2);

            Song song2 = new Song("Chạy Ngay Đi", 234879825);
            song2.addArtist(artist1);

            Song song3 = new Song("Hãy Trao Cho Anh", 2387532);
            song3.addArtist(artist1);

            Song song4 = new Song("Chỉ Một Đêm Nữa Thôi (feat. tlinh)", 782643);
            song4.addArtist(artist2);
            song4.addArtist(artist3);

            Song song5 = new Song("Em Là Châu Báu", 298374);
            song5.addArtist(artist2);
            song5.addArtist(artist3);

            // save songs
            songRepository.save(song1);
            songRepository.save(song2);
            songRepository.save(song3);
            songRepository.save(song4);
            songRepository.save(song5);

        };
    }
}

package musicstore.musicselling.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import musicstore.musicselling.Entity.Artist;

public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository<Artist, Long> {

}

package musicstore.musicselling.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import musicstore.musicselling.Entity.Song;

@Repository
public interface SongRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Long> {

}

This is my codes, when i try to run the application, the artist_song table didn't populate any data eventhough both other tables are populated with data.
Can anyone tell me the reason why the artist_song table's data is not populated?
I tried many ways included changing the FetchType from LAZY to EAGER but it still didn't work

This problem is related to the cascading operations. You are declaring Artist as the owner side of the relationship, while your target side is Song. You are storing first the artists and then adding these artists to the songs and lastly saving these songs when it should be the opposite. By the way, when you are using the attribute CascadeType.ALL in your owner side, you don't need to first save the target side and then add the target side to the owner side and save it. You can add the target side to the owner side first and then save it (the owner side).
You have two options, set Song as the main side or modify the way you are storing the entities in the database.
First option:
In your class Song:
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "artist_song", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", nullable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "artist_id", nullable = false)
})
private Set<Artist> artists = new HashSet<>();

In your class Artist:
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "artists")
private Set<Song> songs = new HashSet<>();

Class for persistence:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import app.entity.Artist;
import app.entity.Song;
import app.repository.ArtistRepository;
import app.repository.SongRepository;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@Component
public class Persistence implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ArtistRepository artistRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Create artists
        Artist artist1 = new Artist("Sơn Tùng M-TP", "Vietnamese singer-songwriter and actor.");
        Artist artist2 = new Artist("tlinh", "tlinh is a Vietnamese independent singer and rapper.");
        Artist artist3 = new Artist("RPT MCK", "RPT MCK is a Vietnamese singer and rapper based in Ha Noi.");

        // Create songs and add artists
        Song song1 = new Song("nếu lúc đó", 3794587);
        song1.addArtist(artist2);

        Song song2 = new Song("Chạy Ngay Đi", 234879825);
        song2.addArtist(artist1);

        Song song3 = new Song("Hãy Trao Cho Anh", 2387532);
        song3.addArtist(artist1);

        Song song4 = new Song("Chỉ Một Đêm Nữa Thôi (feat. tlinh)", 782643);
        song4.addArtist(artist2);
        song4.addArtist(artist3);

        Song song5 = new Song("Em Là Châu Báu", 298374);
        song5.addArtist(artist2);
        song5.addArtist(artist3);

        // Save songs, which will cascade and save artists as well
        songRepository.save(song1);
        songRepository.save(song2);
        songRepository.save(song3);
        songRepository.save(song4);
        songRepository.save(song5);
    }

}

Second option:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import app.entity.Artist;
import app.entity.Song;
import app.repository.ArtistRepository;
import app.repository.SongRepository;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@Component
public class Persistence implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ArtistRepository artistRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Create songs
        Song song1 = new Song("nếu lúc đó", 3794587);
        Song song2 = new Song("Chạy Ngay Đi", 234879825);
        Song song3 = new Song("Hãy Trao Cho Anh", 2387532);
        Song song4 = new Song("Chỉ Một Đêm Nữa Thôi (feat. tlinh)", 782643);
        Song song5 = new Song("Em Là Châu Báu", 298374);
    
        // Create artists
        Artist artist1 = new Artist("Sơn Tùng M-TP", "Vietnamese singer-songwriter and actor.");
        Artist artist2 = new Artist("tlinh", "tlinh is a Vietnamese independent singer and rapper.");
        Artist artist3 = new Artist("RPT MCK", "RPT MCK is a Vietnamese singer and rapper based in Ha Noi.");

        // Establish relationships
        artist1.addSong(song2);
        artist1.addSong(song3);
    
        artist2.addSong(song1);
        artist2.addSong(song4);
        artist2.addSong(song5);
    
        artist3.addSong(song4);
        artist3.addSong(song5);

        // Save artists, which will cascade and save songs as well
        artistRepository.save(artist1);
        artistRepository.save(artist2);
        artistRepository.save(artist3);
    }

}

I store the entities in a new class called Persistence because I replicated your code and it was giving me an exception: Detached Entity Passed to Persist.
You can still implement it in the MusicsellingApplication class in the commandLineRunner method, but you would have to remove the attribute cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST (is included in Cascade.ALL) in you owner side. This is because Spring will also try to save the associated object (song). However this object is not attached to this session (reason for the detached exception).

Thank you so much, i tried the second option but need to modify a little bit. I change the Cascadetype.ALL to CascadeType.MERGE and i still need to save the song before save the artist.

Glad it's working for you!
